# MobileVLCKit Audio is working, Video is not working

Tags: ios, swift, vlc, rtmp

I am using xcode 7.2 also used this in xcode 6.4 (Swift) same issue

I am using cocoapod of MobileVLCKit
http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/MobileVLCKit/2.2.1/index.html

I am getting this in console:

```
2015-12-22 18:17:01.296 test11[3626:79386] creating player instance using shared library
[00007ff3d0d850f8] core generic error: option marq-color does not exist
[00007ff3d0d850f8] core generic error: option marq-opacity does not exist
[00007ff3d0d850f8] core generic error: option marq-position does not exist
[00007ff3d0d850f8] core generic error: option marq-refresh does not exist
[00007ff3d0d850f8] core generic error: option marq-size does not exist
[00007ff3d0d850f8] core generic error: option marq-timeout does not exist
[00007ff3d0d850f8] core generic error: option marq-x does not exist
[00007ff3d0d850f8] core generic error: option marq-y does not exist
[00007ff3d10b0cb8] core video output error: video output creation failed
[00007ff3d1058cb8] core decoder error: failed to create video output
[00007ff3d0cbd0a8] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 1000 ms)
[00007ff3d0cbd0a8] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[00007ff3d0cbd0a8] core input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 2693 ms)
```

and my code is:

```
    let a = VLCMedia(URL: NSURL(string: "http://lilanisoft.com/live/images/Ziyarat_Aashura_by_Samavati_Arabic_sub_English.mp4"))
    let v = VLCMediaPlayer()
    v.drawable = self.view
    v.setDelegate(self)
    v.setMedia(a)
    v.play()
```

Let me know If I am doing any mistake.

some more video urls(if you are thinking video format issue) are:

rtmp://5.79.86.21/live//ih
http://makkah1live.itworkscdn.net/makkah2live/sunnatv_360p/playlist.m3u8
http://lilanisoft.com/live/images/Ziyarat-e-Arbaeen.mp4

Comment: Please give "-vvvv" as option to VLCMediaPlayer and most the output to reveal the reason behind the "video output creation" failure that is already indicated. in your log.

Comment: I am sorry, can you please tell me how to give "-vvvv" as option to VLCMediaPlayer ?

Comment: No idea how you do that with swift. [[VLCMediaPlayer alloc] initWithOptions:@[@"-vvvv]] would be the ObjC syntax.

Comment: Oh you mean that. 
I know how to do.. let me check

Comment: There are too long text in console.
I am not able to view Video on screen :(

Comment: `[00007ff4e20ef8b8] swscale scale debug: 32x32 (32x32) chroma: YUVA -> 16x16 (16x16) chroma: RGBA with scaling using Bicubic (good quality)
[00007ff4e20ef8b8] core scale debug: using video filter2 module "swscale"
[00007ff4e20f38b8] core scale debug: looking for video filter2 module matching "any": 22 candidates`

Comment: Sorry, I need the full log. This is just an excerpt. Use pastebin.com etc to share it :)

Comment: Please find url [of log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9kgi0vjjbryqq46/mp4url.rtf?dl=0)

Comment: @MuhammadRaza hi there,me too facing the same issue. Have you found any solution..?

Comment: Not found any solution till now. I trield Vitamio and it works

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: didn't find any.

Comment: Try using Vitamio